# "msp430-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory" error after moving and restoring the msp430 files

Tags: gcc

I tried manually to change the gcc-msp430 version by removing the 4.6.3 file in `/usr/lib/gcc/msp430` and putting a 4.5.3 from another computer. When this didn't solve my problem, I restored the previous file but now I keep getting this new error:

> "msp430-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory".

I have been trying several suggestions from similar threads (e.g. added `/usr/lib/gcc/msp430` to `PATH`) but nothing seems to work..

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You done goofed. Looks like you didn't restore the files correctly. Reinstall the compiler properly, from the original files, instead of screwing things up by removing pieces of it and putting back different pieces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know now it was a stupid move. Can you help me on how to reinstall the compiler properly?

Comment: No, because I don't know how you installed it originally. Get the original files from where you got them, and reinstall them.

Comment: The thing is it's not my machine I'm just trying to fix a problem (and I created another one). So there is not a default way to do this?

Comment: No, there is no default way to restore files you deleted. You could try adding the `-v` option when running `msp430-gcc` to make it print the exact path it's trying to use for `cc1`, which will tell you which file it's trying to find that is missing.